# Bug in big vote numbers

Tags: bug

[I found this and post it here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3Akermani):

[image: Stack Overflow Bug]

Please see the red bordered rectangle. That is the bug that I found; one number is out of border.

It's easy in CSS 3. Just add `text-overflow: ellipsis` and `overflow: hidden;`.

Comment: btw, it got 700+ votes in past 12 weeks !!! However, it truly deserves the votes.

Comment: @AzizShaikh  I didn't know  that other user posted about this

Comment: No worries. Going forward you may do a little search before posting the question. (Even then sometimes one fails to find a suitable duplicate, where the community would help with VTC).